# Jenkins javadoc plugin doesn't generate documentation

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, javadoc

I have installed Jenkins, create a project and configure it.
I run into a problem, Jenkins do everithing great except documentation generating.

[image: My configuration]

[image: 404 for documentation]

[image: Workspace]

Could anyone point me where I have done mistake, and how fix it?

Thank you.

------------------------ New information ----------

Console output:
[image]

I have renamed `doc` to `javadoc` directory, but it isn't help.

[image]

Here is screenshot of `javadoc` directory contents in console, it is clear that Jenkins plugin didn't generate documentation, but why?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the link be `http://ci.loc:8080/job/Core/doc` instead of `http://ci.loc:8080/job/Core/javadoc` ?

Comment: I tried both links, neither work.

Comment: I have renamed directory to javadoc so it won't confuse anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are expecting the Jenkins plugin to produce the documentation.  The Jenkins plugin merely copies files from the job's workspace folder to the build's archive area and provides a link to it.  If your build steps don't produce Javadoc, then Jenkins won't be able to archive and provide a link to  it.

Does your pom file include the maven-javadoc-plugin?

Are your build steps invoking a goal that includes Javadoc generation?

For example, "mvn jar" would compile Java and build the jar but not build the javadocs.  Clearly you have executed a goal that executes the tests and provides a code coverage report, but that does not trigger the Javadoc goals either.  You would need to make sure your build steps include a javadoc goal - i.e., mvn javadoc:javadoc.  The standard goals can be found here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/plugin-info.html .

Comment: Thank you. You are right, Jenkins use Maven to generate documentation. After I added `javadoc:javadoc` everything works like charm!